# How does EntryPoint Works in Docker?

Tags: bash, docker, maven, docker-compose, dockerfile

My DockerFile looks like as follow:

```
FROM maven:2.3.4-jdk-8
  
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
.................................
```

and docker-entrypoint.sh looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
umask 0011
/bin/bash
```

Now as I read online, the entryPoint is the statement that will be executed default when docker run command runs.

If I do:

```
1. docker run -it imageid
```

Shouldn't it open bash as /bin/bash is default statement in Entry Point  ?

```
But instead it does follow:
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.121 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-09T15:51:18+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/59M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

2. docker run -itd imageid bash
   It starts the container. So what does bash has to do here in the end?Isn't it same as previous command ?
3. Why does not the 2nd statement shows me the bash prompt.Why it has to come through docker exec command?

Comment: How are you building this image? I don't see `maven:2.3.4-jdk-8` base image

Comment: Make sure your minimal example could be reproduceable.

Comment: This Dockerfile should be build-able. As above asked, how are you building it?

Comment: I am building by using docker build command

Answer (score 0):

If you specify both [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) and [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

- `ENTRYPOINT` is the executable
- `CMD` (as an array) is the parameters for the executable

If you specify only [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

- as a string (e.g. `CMD echo "This is a test." | wc -`), it runs in a shell
- as an array (e.g. `CMD ["/usr/bin/wc", "--help"]`), it runs without a shell

---

Here's an example running a shell script:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./example.sh .

CMD ["./example.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the Docker documentation,
`ENTRYPOINT has two forms:`

The exec form, which is the preferred form:

`ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "param1", "param2"]`
The shell form:

`ENTRYPOINT command param1 param2`

if you use the shell form, the ENTRYPOINT command will be a subcommand of `/bin/bash` and will not receive signals, and also will have a PID of 1, not receive Unix signals, and will not receive a SIGTERN from the `docker stop  command.